# What's the name of this pear cultivar? (green skin with brown coating)

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees, fruits, pear

What's the name of this pear cultivar? It has a green skin but it can have a coating in brown color.  On Wikimedia commons, the ones looking closer to this are "Bojniczanka.jpg" and "Pyrus a1.jpg". Is this a variety of Anjou?

Does that brown coating have a name?

[image: Link1] - [image: Link2]

Comment: They just look like good old Conference pears to me https://www.123rf.com/photo_3998695_small-group-of-pears-conference-on-white.html

Comment: @Fructibus Please post an update or an answer if you are convinced you found it.

Answer (score 2):

That brown 'coating' is called russeting. The cultivar is hard, because of all the varieties that have russetting. The shape looks a lot like [Bosc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosc_pear) (known for the shape and russeting).

[image]

Comment: Thanks but now I'm quite convinced that they are conference pears.